# MySQL - выборка по частичному совпадению одного поля. Как сделать?

Tags: mysql, оптимизация

**Дано:**

Есть записи в таблице table, у которых поле a содержатся следующие данные.

```
1 - ][122][100][2349][123][3299][31][
2 - [119][122][100][123][5850][31][
3 - ][122][123][67][100][31][80][
4 - ][122][123][100][267][31][5559][
5 - ][119][122][100][267][4469][226][
```

и т.д.

**Необходимо:**

Допустим, я нахожусь на странице, в которой выводятся вся информация (все поля) по записи 1. Мне нужно сделать блок - похожие записи.

**Критерий отбора:**

Совпадение по 3 цифрам в квадратных скобках.
В данном случае, например (из предложенных), можно вывести записи 2 и 4. Т.к. и там и там есть [122] [100] [123]

**Уточнение:**

Последовательность цифр может отличаться.

**Вопрос:**

Как лучше всего это сделать? Чтобы быстро работало и не было нагрузки на диск и процессор. В таблице на данный момент около 40000 записей. Кроме этого на сервере много других сайтов с большим объемом данных.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте условие LIKE для поиска по базе. Вот статья по этой теме [MYSQL LIKE](https://oracleplsql.ru/like-mysql.html)

Comment: С условием LIKE я работал. Если бы нужно было просто вытащить поля, где, например, есть %[122]%, то это вообще не проблема.  Но здесь всё сложнее. Нужно найти те записи, где 3 цифры могут совпасть, причем порядок разный! И между ними могут быть другие цифры.

Comment: @Рахим Вы можете написать  LIKE %1% и php вам найдет все записи в которых есть число 1 в любой последовательности. Если будет [123][213][321] То LIKE выведет все три ячейки потому что в них есть число 1.

Comment: Это понятно. Вы не понимаете, что мне нужно. И чтобы вот такого 1 не было, для этого поиск идет через LIKE %[$num]%